# MongoDB on Android - socket timeout

Tags: android, mongodb, mlab

I want to connect my Android app to remote MongoDB database:

```
try {
            String str = "";
            MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://byulent:mypass@ds231549.mlab.com:31549/mydb");
            MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
            MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase(uri.getDatabase());
            MongoCollection<Document> photos = db.getCollection("photos");
            FindIterable<Document> cursor = photos.find();
            Iterator i = cursor.iterator();
            while (i.hasNext()){
                Log.d("obj", i.next().toString());
            }
            //Toast.makeText(context, "Succesfully connected to MongoDB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("mongodb", e.getMessage());
        }
```

But when I try to get data from DB, I see this error:

```
E/mongodb: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state 
is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=ds231549.mlab.com:31549, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING,
exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by 
{java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to ds231549.mlab.com/34.245.70.193 
(port 31549) after 20000ms}}]
```

Why this error occurs and how to fix it?

Comment: You really should not try to connect to MongoDB directly from an Android application. It's really bad practice to do that. It is a security risk since it is possible for malicious users to find your connection string. It is much better practice to write an HTTP API to be the interface between the client and the database. That being said, this looks like a connectivity issue so you might find mLab's connectivity troubleshooting docs helpful: https://docs.mlab.com/connecting/#help.

Comment: @tfogo, i tried to set the `ConnectTimeout` and the `SocketTimeout` manually, but error still occurs